# Combine data in 3 tables when data is missing in 3rd table using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with a scenario in mySQL : 
I have 3 tables,
ClassRoll:

```
roll_no | name
123     | jack
456     | jill
789     | miriam
```

StudMarks:

```
name | Subject | marks
jack | math    | 15 
jill | science | 12
```

ExtraCurricularActivity:

```
name  | activity
jill  | singing
miriam| dancing
```

I need a query which will result : StudentSummary as

```
name  | subject | marks | activity
jack  | math    | 15    | NA
jill  | science | 12    | singing
miriam| NA      | NA    | dancing
```

I tried different ways using joins but i am unable to obtain a desired result.

Comment: Show us what you tried - (hint: you need an OUTER JOIN for this)

Comment: I would go about reviewing your schema. Using names as a unique identifier between tables is not good practise

Comment: @Strawberry Here is what I tried :

Comment: @Strawberry: 1. `SELECT
  cr.name,
  sm.marks,
  sm.subject,
  eca.activity
FROM ClassRoll cr
LEFT JOIN StudMarks sm
  ON sm.name = cr.name,
 extracurricularactivity eca
WHERE eca.name = cr.name; ` 
2. 
`SELECT cr.name,
(CASE WHEN sm.name=cr.name THEN sm.marks ELSE 'NA' END ) marks,
(CASE WHEN sm.name=cr.name THEN sm.subject ELSE 'NA' END ) subject,
(CASE WHEN eca.name=cr.name THEN eca.activity ELSE 'NA' END ) activity
FROM 
ClassRoll cr, StudMarks sm, extracurricularactivity eca
WHERE cr.name=sm.name AND cr.name=eca.name;`

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD You are right about it. But since I do not have write access to the db i'm trying to find a soln with the current scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` (or right depending on the sequence):

```
SELECT
  r.name,
  s.marks,
  s.subject,
  e.activity
FROM ClassRoll r
LEFT JOIN StudMarks s
  ON s.name = r.name
LEFT JOIN ExtraCurricularActivity e
ON e.name = r.name
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I neva thought of applying the left join on the third table instead was trying with WHERE clause. (Messing it up even more)

Comment: You're welcome, take some time to study the join [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), it's one of the fundamental concept in sql.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you the expected result:

```
select t1.name,t1.subject, case when t1.makrs is null then "NA" else t1.marks end as marks, t2.activity from StudMarks t1 left join ExtraCurricularActivity t2 on  t1.name=t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name, s.subject, s.marks, e.activity FROM ClassRoll c LEFT JOIN StudMarks s ON c.name = s.name LEFT JOIN ExtraCurricularActivity e ON c.name = e.name
```